# backtracking sudoku solver in python leetcode problem

Tags: python-3.6

I am calculating the correct output, but when it's returning  to main calling function my sudoku board array  doesn't get modified , it's printing the original board values.
I am not able to figure it out why it's happening and how to solve it.

```
class Solution:
def solveSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    
    if self.solve(board,0,0):#after this board is giving its old values not the modfied
        return board


def solve(self,board,row,col):
    if row == len(board):# here board is calculating correct output
        return True
    
    ni = 0
    nj = 0
    
    if (col == len(board[0]) -1):
        ni = row + 1
        nj = 0
    else:
        ni = row
        nj = col + 1
        
    if (board[row][col] != "."):
        self.solve(board,ni,nj)
    
    
    else:
        for p in range(1,10):
            if (self.isValid(board,row,col,p) == True):
                board[row][col] = str(p)
                self.solve(board,ni,nj)
                board[row][col] = "."


def isValid(self,board,x,y,p):
    for j in range(len(board[0])):
        if board[x][j] == str(p):
            return False
    
    for i in range(len(board[0])):
        if board[i][y] == str(p):
            return False
    
    si = (x//3)*3
    sj = (y//3)*3
    
    
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[si+i][sj+j] == str(p):
                return False
    return True
```

Input:
[["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]

my output:
[["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]

expected output:
[["5","3","4","6","7","8","9","1","2"],["6","7","2","1","9","5","3","4","8"],["1","9","8","3","4","2","5","6","7"],["8","5","9","7","6","1","4","2","3"],["4","2","6","8","5","3","7","9","1"],["7","1","3","9","2","4","8","5","6"],["9","6","1","5","3","7","2","8","4"],["2","8","7","4","1","9","6","3","5"],["3","4","5","2","8","6","1","7","9"]]

problem link on leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-ii/472/backtracking/2796/

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the issue:

```
    if (self.isValid(board,row,col,p) == True):
            board[row][col] = str(p)
            self.solve(board,ni,nj)
            board[row][col] = "."
```

I am not gonna deep dive into your entire algorithm will just analyze this part. You are setting the board value if valid:

```
    board[row][col] = str(p)
```

then calling this function:

```
       self.solve(board,ni,nj)
```

and this function eventually returns only True. Imagine you are keep calling same function, first value must be valid, but if the next value is not valid, then you have to return somewhere "False" from "solve()". So if any value is invalid, you have to delete what you inserted, revert the "board[row][col]" to the original value.

since solve() always returns true, after all the functions are popped off the stack, this  `board[row][col] = "."`  will be executed, so you never modify the state. `board[row][col] = "."` this has to be executed only after you return `False`